# chai-http not always seeing ETag header, possibly due to CORS?

Tags: http, chai, etag, chai-http

I'm written a suite of tests using mocha (6.2.2), chai (4.2.0) and chai-http (4.3.0) to test a micro-service we've written. Sometimes, the ETag header we add ourselves (first removing the 'Express' one using an on-headers listener) doesn't appear in the response received to a call to chai.request. Observations are:

- if the tests run on the same host as the micro-service, the responses
  received will ALWAYS have the required ETag header;
- if the tests run on a different host to the micro-service, the response received will
  SOMETIMES have the ETag header;
- the tests failing because of missing ETag headers are always the same
  ones (even though the code is pretty much the same);
- Hitting the micro-service REST endpoints using POSTMAN ALWAYS correctly returns a response with the ETag header;

From the observations, I'm pretty confident our micro-service is fine.

From [here](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/),

> Note: When running in a web browser, the same-origin policy only allows Chai HTTP to read certain headers, which can cause assertions to fail.

(Even though we're not running in a browser, I guess the principle still holds). I've tried adding an access-control-expose-headers header to the micro-service response (which includes etag) but this doesn't solve the issue.

I'm sort of assuming it's a CORS issue: other possibilities are that chai-http doesn't like the etag value; an example of a missing etag is:

```
166-Kd4TGzdykcFKsmm2U4aTYxewdzA
```

However, adding arbitrary headers such as 'Blah' with this value always results in the header being present...

Responses include the following CORS headers:

```
{
   "server":"openresty/1.15.8.2",
   "date":"Tue, 24 Mar 2020 13:21:37 GMT",
   "content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8",
   "transfer-encoding":"chunked",
   "connection":"close",
   "vary":"Accept-Encoding",
   "strict-transport-security":"max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains",
   "x-powered-by":"Express",
   "access-control-allow-origin":"*",
   "access-control-expose-headers":"ETag,.....",
   "access-control-allow-credentials":"true",
   "access-control-allow-methods":"PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE",
   "content-encoding":"gzip"
}
```

(I've also tried adding access-control-allow-headers but these don't seem to be set correctly: I don't think these are relevant here though).

I'd be interested if anyone has come across similar issues with chai-http/ETag/CORS and came up with a solution??

Mike Beale

Comment: If you’re not running code in a browser, then the problem isn’t CORS-related. CORS is only relevant to frontend JavaScript code running in a browser.

Comment: Thanks @sideshowbarker:  the only other option is is that chai-http (or chai?) is bizarrely swallowing some ETag headers. Anyone else seen this?

 Is there anything special about ETags here?I did see something somewhere about headers being returned lazily, but can't confirm this...